# accessibility of wpf textbox validation feedback

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, accessibility

I have a textbox that a user puts a server name into, and it's validated as an FQDN as he types. I also have a style that gets applied when the validation fails that makes the background of the textbox pink. However, **I don't want this to happen when high contrast mode is on** and I can't really seem to find much literature on how to accomplish this.

Here's the textbox/style:

```
<TextBox ...>
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ServerName.HasErrorsToShow}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="TextBox.Background" Value="Pink" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

How can I accomplish this? Thanks!

EDIT 1:

I tried using a MultiTrigger. It seems promising, but I can't quite get it right. This chunk of code worked (for testing whether I could base decisions on high contrast):

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.HighContrast}}" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="TextBox.Background" Value="Pink" />
    </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

But when I tried adding the MultiTrigger, I got a "Set property 'System.Windows.FrameworkElement.Style' threw an exception" exception. The inner exception was "Must have non-null value for 'Property'". Here's the code for that:

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <MultiTrigger>
        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Binding="{Binding ServerName.HasErrorsToShow}" Value="True" />
            <Condition Binding="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.HighContrast}}" Value="False" />
        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Setter Property="TextBox.Background" Value="Pink" />
    </MultiTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested this code out, but perhaps you could use a `MultiTrigger` and bind to the `HighContrast` property of the `SystemParameters` object.  Something like this:

[removed, see below]

Note: I'm pretty sure the `HighContrast` property of the static `SystemParameters` class is not a dependency property, and won't raise `NotifyPropertyChanged`, so if the user changes the setting while the application is already open, I don't believe the trigger will fire.

Edit:
This style seems to do the job for me.

```
<Style x:Key="MyTextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
  <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.HighContrastKey}}"/>
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
  <Style.Triggers>
    <MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Binding="{Binding ServerName.HasErrorsToShow}" Value="true"/>
            <Condition  Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Tag}" Value="True"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
    </MultiDataTrigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: You could also change the entire style based on the `HighContrast` setting.  See [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/ba9a379b-4f02-408c-954b-6057e6d0a1b5) for an example.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried what you suggested, but I ran into an exception. I've put the results in Edit 1 in the question.

Comment: What is the original value for TextBox.Background?  Is it possible that value is `null`?

Comment: It's very likely. Is the only way around this to set it? I'd like to leave it null, as I assume that lets some default have its way.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "lets some default have its way" but setting it to `null` probably isn't necessary.  If you want it to be transparent, use `Transparent`, otherwise, don't assign it and it will use the default look and feel for a `TextBox`.  For TextBoxes that are using your style, you can still override it at the individual `TextBox` level by assigning their own `Background` value.

Comment: Haha, no I'm not setting background to null. I just meant that I wasn't setting it. I tried setting the background explicitly on this particular TextBox, but I'm getting the same exception still. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, I've edited the answer to add a style that works for me.  Give that one a try.